# Laravel: Issue with Sending Verification Email to User Upon Registration

Tags: email, laravel-6, php-8, user-registration, email-verification

I'm currently facing an issue where the verification email is not being sent to users after they submit the registration form in my Laravel application.

Here's what I have already checked and confirmed:

Email Configuration: I have verified that my Laravel mail configuration contains the correct SMTP server details, including host, port, encryption type, and any other required settings for my email service provider.
User Data and Workflow: The user data is successfully stored in the database upon registration, but the verification email is not being triggered or sent to the user.

Error Handling: I have checked the application logs and there are no related error messages or exceptions regarding the email-sending process.

I'm using Laravel version 6.20.44 and PHP version 8.0 and would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Are there any additional steps or configuration settings that I might have missed?

Here is my Register Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

        $user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

        return $user;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance!